# Is there a reliable method of testing function processing time?

Tags: python, unit-testing, optimization

I would like to include some stress tests in my test suite that can flag up if a change has had a significant change to processing time.

Currently I have the below using `timeit`

```py
from timeit import repeat
time = min(repeat(lambda: do_something_stressful(), number=2000, repeat=5))
assert 0.220 < time < 0.26
```

This mostly works when running on a consistent development machine but is obviously significantly different on a different processor or cloud machine.

Is there any other way to test the performance of a python function?

Comment: Use the `timeit` module for benchmarking

Comment: You will need to establish a benchmark for each system you are going to run the tests on so you have something to compare values against.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. It would be good if something like this was included with timeit.